# React re-rendering of nested list functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Should not custom component `CheckboxLabels` retrieve different `checked` prop after each `handleCheckboxChange` call? Currently I can not get the clicked checkbox to checked  state before closing the enveloping upper list. Only opening and closing the upper list updates the state of the nested checkbox components.

```
type CheckboxLabelsProps = {
  columns: string[]
  table: string
  checked: Map<string, boolean>
  handleCheckboxChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

function CheckboxLabels({ columns, table, checked, handleCheckboxChange }: CheckboxLabelsProps) {
  return (
    <FormGroup>
      {columns.map((column, index) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={column}
          label={column}
          value={`${table}-${column}`}
          control={<Checkbox checked={checked.has(`${table}-${column}`) ? checked.get(`${table}-${column}`) : false} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} />}
        />
        ))}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}


export default function NestedList({ items }: PropsType) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState([] as boolean[]);
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(new Map() as Map<string, boolean>);

  useEffect(() => {
    // sets open state as array of false
  }, [items])

  useEffect(() => {
    // sets checked state for each nested checkbox element as false
  }, [])

  const handleCheckboxChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const [table, column] = event.target.value.split('-');
    const newChecked = checked;
    const key = `${table}-${column}`;
    newChecked.set(key, !checked.get(`${table}-${column}`));
    setChecked(newChecked);
  };

  const handleClick = (index: number) => {
    const collapsedIndex: number = index;
    const newOpen = [...open];
    newOpen[collapsedIndex] = !(open[collapsedIndex]);
    setOpen(newOpen);
  };

  return (
    <List>
      {items.map((item, index) => 
        {
          const tables = Object.keys(item.payload.columns);
          const columnsForTable = new Map<string, string[]>();
          tables.forEach((table) => {
              const key = table;
              const value = item.payload.columns[table];
              columnsForTable.set(key, value);
          });
          const columnsFT = Object.entries(Object.fromEntries(columnsForTable.entries()));
          return  columnsFT.map(([table, columns]: [string, string[]], index ) => 
                      (
                        <Box key={table}>
                          <ListItemButton onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                            <InboxIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={table} />
                            {open[index] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                          </ListItemButton>
                            <Collapse in={open[index]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                <List key={table} component="div" disablePadding>
                                  <ListItem sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', ml: 3 }}>
                                      <CheckboxLabels columns={columns} table={table} checked={checked} handleCheckboxChange={handleCheckboxChange}/>
                                    </Box>
                                  </ListItem>
                                </List>
                            </Collapse>
                          </Box>
                      ))
          })
      }
    </List>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your `handleCheckboxChange` implementation; you should be creating a new copy of the `checked` Map rather than reusing the old one. This is because, as a performance optimization, React only rerenders after calling `setState` when the new state value is different from the old one (I believe by using `Object.is()` as the notion of equality). However, by reusing the same Map instance, the reference value of the `checked` Map never changes, so React never knows to rerender.

The following implementation of `handleCheckboxChange` should fix your issue:

```js
const handleCheckboxChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const [table, column] = event.target.value.split('-');
  const newChecked = new Map(checked); // <-- create copy
  const key = `${table}-${column}`;
  newChecked.set(key, !checked.get(`${table}-${column}`));
  setChecked(newChecked);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might have thought of default deep copy or something similar implementing it. Really appreciate your time.